# Is $f^p$ Lipschitz for every $p \geq 1$ whenever $f$ is?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $X$ is a metric space of bounded diameter and $f:X\rightarrow R$
is Lipschitz. Is $f^p$ Lipschitz for every $p \geq 1$? What is its Lipschitz constant in terms of the constant of $f$?

Comment: If $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ then either by $f^p$ you mean $(f(x))^p$ or we need $X\subsetneq \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p >1$ and $f$ is Lipschitz of rank $L$.

Since $f$ is Lipschitz and $X$ is bounded, then $R = \{ f(x) | x \in X \}$
is bounded.

Let $\phi(t) = t^p$ and note that $\phi'(t) = p t^{p-1}$ and hence
there is some $K$ such that $|\phi'(t)| \le K$ for $t \in R$ and
so $|\phi(t)-\phi(s)| \le K |t-s|$ for $s,t \in R$.

Hence $|f^p(x)-f^p(y)| = |\phi(f(x))-\phi(f(y))| \le K |f(x)-f(y)| \le K L d(x,y)$ and so $f^p$ is Lipschitz of rank no more than $KL$.

Comment: Or in short: the composition of Lipschitz functions is Lipschitz. The only technicality here is that your $\phi$ is only locally Lipschitz in general, so we need the range of $f$ to be bounded to "pretend $\phi$ is globally Lipschitz".

Comment: And the reason this doesn't work for $p<1$ is that $\phi'(t)$ is not bounded in that case.